# how to correct any typing errors with ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, logcat, android-logcat

it's logcat:

```
Process: com.example.SmsService, PID: 21748
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.example.SmsService.VideoView$3.getView(VideoView.java:168)
        at com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView.fillListRight(HorizontalListView.java:753)
        at com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView.fillList(HorizontalListView.java:695)
        at com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView.onLayout(HorizontalListView.java:567)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1662)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14891)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5890)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

shows any typing errors in this line:

```
 if (title.getText() == lines_image.get(position)) {
              Picasso.with(retval.getContext()).load(url_first + lines_image.get(position)).into(image_list_icon);
           }
```

Here is [all](https://gist.github.com/diha-o/53023d030066a582c2f5) the code in my class. probably a mistake because I did not have the item in the list under the number **6** in `lines_image`, but I do not know how it would be possible to avoid it. help please!!!!!
Line where will be error:

```
   if (title.getText() == lines_image.get(position)) {
```

and all my code fom `getView()` method:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_leyout, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        image_list_icon = (ImageView)retval.findViewById(R.id.image_fromlist);
       // title.setText(dataObjects[position%dataObjects.length]);

       title.setText(lines_image.get(position%lines_image.size()));


          if (title.getText() == lines_image.get(position)) {
              Picasso.with(retval.getContext()).load(url_first + lines_image.get(position)).into(image_list_icon);
           }

                ///// another, for video /////
                if (position == mSelectedItem) {
                    retval.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    retval.getBackground().setAlpha(80);
                    retval.setMinimumHeight(retval.getHeight() + 15);
                    image_list_icon.getLayoutParams().height = image_list_icon.getLayoutParams().height + 30;
                    image_list_icon.getLayoutParams().width = image_list_icon.getLayoutParams().width + 30;


                    if (title.getText() == lines_image.get( position)) {
                        String vidAddress = lines_video.get(position);
                        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
                        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
                         vidView.start();
                    }


                } else if (position != mSelectedItem)

                {

                    image_list_icon.getLayoutParams().height = image_list_icon.getLayoutParams().height - 5;

                }
                return retval;
            }




};
```

Comment: Please post code for method `getView` from class `VideoView` and mark line number 168.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, ok, refresh.

Comment: `lines_image` has only 6 items and you are trying to get 7th item. Check where you are setting values in it. See if `getCount()` method is returning wrong count.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, I wrote in the question that I know this , but here's how to do then check right?

Comment: I mentioned something about your `getCount` method too, didn't I? Please see my answer.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, no I need looped listView!

Comment: Then change your code everywhere where it says `lines_image.get(position)`. Your position should never be greater than size of `lines_image`

Comment: @Rohit5k2, but as I could then do check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `getCount()` method as

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
    return lines_image.size();
}
```

***EDIT***

If you want a looped listview then replace every occurrence of

```
lines_image.get(position);
```

with

```
lines_image.get(position % lines_image.size());
```